# Can someone contruct a sequence $u_n$ of positive numbers that satisfies the asymptotic behaviour

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I am looking for a sequence $u_n$ of positive numbers such that
$$\frac{u_{n+1}-u_{n}+1}{u_n}\sim \frac{c}{n\ln(n)},$$
as $n\to \infty$, for some $c>0$.
 I have a feeling that there is no such sequence.
Here, $\sim$ means that 
$$\lim\frac{u_{n+1}-u_{n}+1}{u_n} \frac{n\ln(n)}{c}=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

What about
$$ u_n=(1+\frac{c}{n})^{\frac{1}{\ln(n)}}$$
It is straightforwardly shown that 
$$u_n=1+\frac{c}{n\ln(n)} +O\left(\frac{1}{n^2\ln(n)}\right)$$
and
$$\frac{u_{n+1}-u_{n}+1}{u_n}=\frac{c}{n\ln(n)} +O\left(\frac{1}{n^2\ln(n)}\right) $$

Comment: Thank you Paul Enta. However the sequence $u_n$ that you have indicated goes to $1$ with $n\to\infty$. This seems to contradict you last equation...

Comment: I am sorry, I was not careful enough.